# How to get proccesses currently running semaphores by /proc?

Tags: linux, semaphore

I wonder how to get processes currently running semaphores by `/proc` ? I guess it's possible by SysVIPC subdirectory.But I don't know how to use this commands.

Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: In `/proc/PID/maps`, you can see the memory mapping of a process and POSIX semaphores show up as attached files in `/dev/shm`. I'm not sure about SysV semaphores though.

Comment: @lgeorget and myself have confirmed that both POSIX and SysV semaphores do in fact show up in the `/proc/PID/maps` file for a given PID.

Comment: But apparently, shared memory fragments also show up as entries in `/dev/shm` and they are pretty indistinguishable from semaphores (except if they have clever names).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

My only experience in dealing with semaphores and shared memory is through the use of the command `ipcs`. Take a look at the [ipcs man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ipcs) for more details.

This command shows you what processes have semaphores:

```
$ ipcs -s

------ Semaphore Arrays --------
key        semid      owner      perms      nsems     
0x4d114854 65536      saml       600        8
```

With the semid known we can query for addition info about the PIDs that have semaphores (note there are 8 - the nsems column):

```
$ ipcs -s -i 65536

Semaphore Array semid=65536
uid=500  gid=501     cuid=500    cgid=501
mode=0600, access_perms=0600
nsems = 8
otime = Sun May 12 14:44:53 2013  
ctime = Wed May  8 22:12:15 2013  
semnum     value      ncount     zcount     pid       
0          1          0          0          0         
1          1          0          0          0         
2          1          0          0          2265      
3          1          0          0          2265      
4          1          0          0          0         
5          1          0          0          0         
6          1          0          0          4390      
7          1          0          0          4390
```

The pid column are these processes. You can either look them up using `ps` or look through the `/proc` file-system, `/proc/<pid>`.

For example:

```
$ more /proc/2265/cmdline 
mono
```

#### POSIX & SystemV

Building off of a comment left by @lgeorget I dug into my PID 2265's `/proc/2265/map` contents and did find the following `/dev/shm` references:

```
$ grep shm /proc/2265/maps 
7fa38e7f6000-7fa38ebdf000 rw-s 00000000 00:11 18517                      /dev/shm/mono-shared-500-shared_fileshare-grinchy-Linux-x86_64-40-12-0
7fa38f0ca000-7fa38f0cb000 rw-s 00000000 00:11 18137                      /dev/shm/mono.2265
7fa3967be000-7fa3967d3000 rw-s 00000000 00:11 18516                      /dev/shm/mono-shared-500-shared_data-grinchy-Linux-x86_64-328-12-0
```

Comment: As far as I know, only System V semaphores (those you get with `semget(2)`) show up in `ipcs -s` so if you're using POSIX semaphores (those you get with `sem_open(2)`), you have to use another method.

Comment: Know of any terminal commands that will return the sem_open(2) variety? Just curious. Everything I know about semaphores is in the answer above 8-).

Comment: No, that's the problem. ;) As the `ipcs` manpage say: "The  Linux  ipcs utility is not fully compatible to the POSIX ipcs utility." so I'm not sure they even thought of something for POSIX IPC. Maybe a future release of `ipcs` :).

Comment: the contents of the `map` are both variety's of semaphores thought, correct?

Comment: I guess so. One way or another, semaphores have to be attached somewhere in the process memory. But I was not sure SysV semaphores were also created in the pseudo-filesystem `/dev/shm`. Now, we have the answer. :)