# Meaning of pid 0 in "ipcs -s -i <id>"

Tags: linux

Referring to this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75547/how-to-get-proccesses-currently-running-semaphores-by-proc/308002), and particularly to the output of `ipcs -s -i 65536`, what is the meaning of pid 0?

For example, in my system:

```
# ipcs -s

------ Semaphore Arrays --------
key        semid      owner      perms      nsems     
0x02004393 5013511    user_one   744        1         
0x53020010 753673     user_two   744        1         


# ipcs -s -i 5013511

Semaphore Array semid=5013511
uid=702  gid=501     cuid=702    cgid=501
mode=0744, access_perms=0744
nsems = 1
otime = Not set                   
ctime = Mon Sep  5 17:35:42 2016  
semnum     value      ncount     zcount     pid       
0          0          0          0          0
```

Answer (score 0):

`0`  is not a valid pid. For a SysV semaphore it means that no processed has called `semop` on it yet.

Once it becomes nonzero, it'll be the `pid` of the last process to call `semop` on that particular semaphore in the semaphore array.